# WPF: Problem with overlapping controls and grid column widths

Tags: wpf, grid, controls

I have a problem regarding a parent grid with a control in it that overlaps a tabcontrol.

I need the child grid (in the tab control) to resize its columns according to the overlapping control. 
Specifically, when the overlapping control is resized (due to resize of the window for example) the child grid inside the tabcontrol needs to resize its columns so that the child controls inside the tabcontrol grid isn't overlapped by the control that overlaps the tabcontrol.

I sincerely hope someone here knows a solution for this problem, I've been fighting with it for days :)

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Req

edit: In response to the comments below:

Absolutely - I figured I should have, but seeing that I was/am at work I didn't have the code handy. But I can write up a similar example of the XAML.

```
<Grid Name="parentGrid" >
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TabControl Name="tabCtrl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <TabItem Name="tabItem1">
      <Grid Name="tabCtrlGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" /> <!-- This is the column I want to resize according to the overlapping image control below -->
          <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Name="someChildControl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
      </Grid>
    </TabItem>
  </TabControl>

  <Image Name="overlappingImg" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" /> <!-- whenever the screen/window is resized, the parentGrid resizes, and thus resizing this overlapping image. -->
</Grid>
```

What needs to happen is that column 0 in the tabCtrlGrid needs to resize its width to fit the width of the overlapping area of the image. That way someChildControl is never overlapped by the image, regardless of how it's resized.

Hopefully that makes it a little more clear :)

Comment: Can you please post some XAML code?

Comment: Or beter: show us some pictures that show how the resizing should work.

Comment: As far as I can test and see the Button is never overlapped by the image as it is using half of the tab which is using two equally wide columns so the button never cross into the middle column. What am I missing?

Comment: My example may be a poor one as I didn't fully test it, but rewrote it from memory and I am not using equally wide columns. I didn't think of this example actually defeating the whole purpose of my question - I apologise. In my case, the image does in fact overlap, as the columns can be of variable width and not necessarily equal width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this look?

```
    <Grid Name="parentGrid" Background="LightGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Aqua"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Tab controller" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Aqua"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Up down nav" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Height="160" Fill="BlanchedAlmond"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CoverArt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" Height="160"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightGray" />
            <TextBlock Text="Tab content" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: @Phil. Very interesting, you're right, it doesn't get clipped, however it's still placed inside the TabControl and to the right of the child control. I'm not sure if it's possible to place it left of the TabControl's clipping area :(

Comment: @Requiem: I seem to have misunderstood your requirement. Where is the rectangle in this example supposed to go?

Comment: @Phil: What I'm trying to do is a database application of movies, video games or the like. The cover art is suppsoed to be placed in the top left corner of the application window, with the tab control containing the info of the movie/game/whatever, at the bottom right. The cover art is supposed to slightly overlap the tabcontrol, however the tab control must adjust its contents so that the overlapping image doesn't conceal any of the info in the tab. So in essence, the cover art and TabControl are in the parent grid, the info is in a grid located inside the TabItem

Comment: So your tab headers are down the right, and your tab contents are in the middle? Then you want to make sure the cover art doesn't obscure the content of the selected tab.

Comment: @Phil: My tab headers are in fact collapsed and invisible. The selected tab item in the tab control is controlled by the buttons in the lower left corner through code-behind. The tab contents are in the middle, yes - in the shaded area you see where the Release Date label is located. And yes, I want to make sure that whatever width/height the cover art is, the contents of the tab control are adjusted so they aren't obscured by the cover, but also adjusts inward so they're not floating out in the middle... I'd like them to follow the width of the cover.

Comment: @Requiem: I have a cunning plan; create two grids. One grid that has your cover art and tab contents super-imposed over a grid that has all your other stuff. If you can wait I'll try to prototype it this evening. Also, if you make the buttons in the bottom left a `ListBox` (or something similar) you may be able to bind its `SelectedItem` directly to the `SelectedItem` of your `TabControl` in `XAML`. (Rather than coding event handlers in the code behind)

Comment: @Requiem: I've modified the answer.

Comment: I actually played around with that idea for a while, but I couldn't get the dang cover art and tab contents to share a grid without the cover art being a part of the tab contents, which is exactly what I'm wanting to avoid since the cover art needs to be independent of what tab is selected/shown.

Comment: Your modified answer is very close, however my tab control is actually in the middle (containing the tab contents), where the tab control you included, is located in the lower left corner where I put a stackpanel containing the buttons to control which tab is selected in the tab control. Plus you have set the cover art to be a set width/height, where I need it to be variable in relation to the screen width/height (Gridunit type star). I'm starting to think maybe what I am wanting can't be done.

Comment: @Requiem: The column width containing the cover art is set to `Auto` so it will size to its content. I set the size of the cover art for demonstration purposes only - dynamic will work just as well (you can test this by playing with the size of the cover art in the example above). Anything you don't mind being obscured should go in the parent grid, anything else should go in the nested grid.

Comment: @Requiem: Actually you should be able to set the width on the grid column or the cover art without any issues. If you change the size on the rectangle you'd need to set the same size of the textblock in the sample above.

Comment: @Phil: Actually looking at your suggestion here, I think I just had an idea! I'll play around with what you posted here and my idea, and let you know shortly :) Thanks so much for your effort, it's been invaluable :)

Comment: @Requiem: By the way, if you judge a post to be correct you can click the check mark next to it on the left. It marks the question as answered to a satisfactory level. (It also awards you 2 reputation points, and the person who answered 15 reputation points)

Comment: oh I fully intend to - I think your answer here may have guided me to the right path - I'm currently testing out your answer combined with my idea... If it turns out to be working, I fully intend to mark this as solved and award you your well-deserved reputation :) Turns out you can nest a grid inside a TabControl, but outside of your TabItems... This (I hope) will allow me to have independent controls outside the TabItems, yet still be able to share the nested grid between independent controls and the TabItem contents

Comment: Apparently that didn't work either... It just moves the tab button/pane inside the grid... Was hoping I could nest the contents of the tab inside the nested grid and keep the tabs on the edge of the control :(

Comment: Is that a problem? Is the tab pane a visual artifact?

Comment: I found the solution! There's the possibility to share columns across multiple grids by setting a share scope: <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn" Width="Auto"/> then set the other columns in other grids you want to share size to the same group name :)

Comment: @Phil: you have been a tremendous help and you've spent so much time trying to help me with my little problem - I honestly can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Requiem: You're welcome, of course. I'm just sorry I couldn't understand your problem well enough to give you a proper solution.

Comment: don't even worry about it - it was a quite complicated setup and explaining something like that is a nightmare. I would've sent you the code to play with, but I don't have it handy here, and was forced to experiment with makeshift code. You honestly were an amazing help! The simplest solution was simply to make the overlapping part of the image and the tabcontrol share the width of column by using the ShareScope property - I didn't even know such a feature existed!